# MVC3 How To Phone Validation for model structure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my model structure PhoneNumber is not required but if user want to enter a value, it must be entered 10 digits. 
 I tried

```
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Girdiğiniz numara 10 karakter uzunluğunda olmalı")]
```

but it doesn't allow empty entry. 
Is there anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Regular Expression Validator and then find/write a regular expression that validates the phone number. For example in the USA:

```
public class MyRegularExpressions
{
   public const string USPhone = @"^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$|^[2-9]\\d{2}\\d{3}\\d{4}$";
}
```

And then the Atribute used in your model is:

```
[RegularExpression(MyRegularExpressions.USPhone)]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

This way it is not required but when something is entered it has to match the specified regular expression.

If you need to write your own regular expression one of the best sites out there is: http://www.regexr.com/